# Web page becomes unresponsive after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web-applications

I have a webpage in which I am getting some data from the server.I have used servlet to get the data from server.I need to fetch the data in every 5 seconds time inerval.I have used ajax call in my script, but after several calls the webpage becomes unresponsive.I have found one thing that here I have replaced the entire html page again , how can I seperate a particular div from the output html content (here page_html). I want to replace the div only

```
setInterval("update_content();", 5000);

function update_content(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "url", // post it back to itself - use relative path or consistent www. or non-www. to avoid cross domain security issues
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false, // be sure not to cache results
    })
    .done(function( page_html ) {
        var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
        newDoc.write(page_html);
        newDoc.close();         
    });       
}
```

Comment: Use `setInterval(update_content, 5000);` instead of `setInterval("update_content();", 5000);`.

Comment: Are there any errors in a console?

Comment: That's strange. Can you post the minimal reproducable example at JSFIddle.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in async call?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev : Hey I have found the issue , could you help me a little bit more , please see the edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I seperate a particular div from the output html content (here page_html). I want to replace the div only

You can simply change the contents of a `div` using jQuery `html()` method.

```
<div id="yourDivId">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function update_content(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "url", // post it back to itself - use relative path or consistent www. or non-www. to avoid cross domain security issues
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false, // be sure not to cache results
    })
    .done(function(page_html) {
        $("#yourDivId").html(page_html);
    });       
}
```

This method will load the HTML using AJAX, and then replace HTML contents of `#yourDivId` with loaded data. This is what AJAX usually used for.

Comment: I have a response html , and according to this if I have a div and I am making an ajax call , it will load the response data to my div right?

Comment: I want to load a specific div from my response to my div id , here the entire response will load to my div id right?

Comment: @JamesHoffman Yes, the entire response will replace the target HTML. In order to make it AJAX-style, you need to return only `div` contents in response, but not the whole page.

Comment: How can I return only div content here? I saw a method using filter() and find() but both didn't work out properly , do you have a ny suggestion?